# WPF Windows within Windows Forms as MDI where do I put the contents of App.xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windowsformsintegration

Due to circumstances beyond my control I must host some WPF screens inside a Windows Form app as an MDI child.  I belive I know how to do this and have moved almost everything over.  However I am not sure what to do with the Styles set in my App.xaml file.

How / where do I set a Global Styles reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the `App.xaml` file is ignored in a WinForms app you will have to use a [RecourceDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in watherver your UI root control is:

```
<Page.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="myresourcedictionary.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

to include local resources you would frist create a `ResourceDictionary`for your local resources and then add the `MergedDictionaries`like so:

```
<Page.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <!--local resources-->
    <Style x:Key="My Style">
    ...
    </Style>

    <!--"global" resources from file-->
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="myresourcedictionary.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: My Wpf window already has a <Windows.Resources> Defined which contains things like Data Templates etc.  When I try to add any references to another dictionary it says:  Resources can only be set once.  Does everything need to be Resource Dictionary instead of only the Global Styles?

Comment: It took me a few minutes to figure out how to get it to play nicely but your answer was spot on.  Thanks a lot!